# Loki to Juno 5 upgrade failure

Tags: updates

CURRENTLY MY LAPTOP RUNNING ON ELEMENTARY os 0.4.1 LOKI. BUT IT'S NOT UPGRADING TO NEW VERSION AFTER CHECKING FOR UPDATE. ERROR REPORTED "TOO FEW ITEMS TO PROCESS"
Request to kindly help on the up gradation process
Ravishankar

Comment: Please don't use ALL CAPS!! http://netiquette.wikia.com/wiki/Rule_number_2_-_Do_not_use_all_caps | Is a pretty old rule in the Net, like washing your hands after going to the bathroom

Answer (score 2):

You can't update from Loki to Juno. You'll need to do a fresh install with a Juno iso.

Don't forget to backup your /home directory as well as your packages and ppas.

Comment: Like he said, elementary OS isn't a rolling release period.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.. But, Di I need to again purchase Juno?

Comment: That's up to you! You can set the price manually to 0 if you don't wanna contribute